# Display text on a text view box (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: layout resource file 1]

[image: layout resource file]

I am a beginner in Android. I have two layout resource files as shown above.
I want to type a word in the first one and click the button, then it is suppose to go to the 2nd layout resource file and  display the word on the text view box. I keep getting an error whenever I try.

Below is the code I wrote

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this, NewLayoutActivity::class.java))
    }
}
```

for the new layout activity

```
class NewLayoutActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout)

    textView.text = ${editText.text}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try `intent

```
    var data2 = editText.text.toString
    val intent = Intent(applicationContext,secondActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("name",data2)
    startActivity(intent)
```

in the second

```
val data = intent.getStringExtra("name")
```

you should learn navigation its better and easier

Answer (score 1):

pass data with intent while open new activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, NewLayoutActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("value", "value you want to pass")
startActivity(intent)
```

And get in second activity as:

```
var bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
var message = bundle!!.getString("value") // if the value is type of String
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code from this

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(this, NewLayoutActivity::class.java))
}
```

to this

```
val value = edit_text_id.text 
button.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity(Intent(this, NewLayoutActivity::class.java)
.putExtra("key", value))
}
```

then, get your value on second activity with this

```
val value = Intent().getStringExtra("key")
text_view_id.text = value
```